# Error while running highstate on minion "No top file or external data matches found"

Tags: linux, salt-stack

I am getting error:

> No top file or external data matches found" when running state.highstate command from salt master.

I have created two minions, one on same node where salt master present and one on another host.

When I am running command `salt '*' state.highstate`, `top.sls` gets successfully executed on node where master is present and fails on another node with above error.

*Minion1 version(Same node as that of master): 2015.8.8(centos)*

*Minion2 version: 0.17.5(ubuntu)*

Comment: saltstack 0.17.5 on the ubuntu box is now 4 years old, are you sure you cannot upgrade it to something more recent? there are various ways to install salt: see https://repo.saltstack.com and https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/

Comment: I am using ubuntu(14.04) version. for that version "repo.saltstack.com" giving latest version as 0.17.5 only. To check what causing an issue i created another Ubuntu host with 14.04 version and installed salt-minion(0.17.5) and issue got resolve.

Comment: So basically what I have learned is that your salt master and minion should at same version otherwise it will give you above error. Anyways @Alberto: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Well, the match on master and minion versions is not strictly required, but since 0.17.5 is 4 years old, maybe is no more compatible with a new version of the master; using the bash bootstrap script you could install a newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved for me now. Issue was with salt master and minion version. I was using salt-minion version different from salt-master version.

My salt-master was running with version 0.17.5 and minion was running with different version. I reinstall minion with correct version. Issue is resolved now.